# Can ENUM (Y | N) be used in relational schema and in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

im working on a database project so far i created a table but im confused if it should in relational schema and mysql : 
ENUM(Y|N) NOT NULL

OR

ENUM('Y','N')  NOT NULL

which one is the correct ones???

Comment: The second one: `ENUM('Y','N')`

Comment: even in relational schema? @TheImpaler

Comment: when specifying types of houses for example it should be separated using (' ',' ')? or using the | @TheImpaler

Answer (score 0):

The second one is valid in MySQL:

```
ENUM('Y','N')
```

Now, please consider that values are stored as ordinals, so when sorting by this column the value `Y` is sorted before `N`.

Comment: what if i want to store different type of houses for example : houseType: Enum[SMALL HOUSE | FAMILY HOUSE | VILLA (7 rooms) |PENT HOUSE| Luxury house| BIG VILLA] as a relational schema and a mysql is this wrong??

Comment: also is ENUM(Y|N)  valid in text relational  schema?

Comment: @anonymous Your example of type of houses is probably not suitable for an ENUM since it's bound to change in the future (next year, a new house type may be defined). If it changes in time, it's more flexible to consider it an entity by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid to use any scalar data type for a column. Using ENUM doesn't necessarily spoil the  relational quality of the table.

As far as being relational, there's no difference between ENUM and using another scalar data type that is restricted to a finite set of values.

In fact, in [SQL and Relational Theory](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920046158.do), Chris Date defines a data type as:

> A named, finite set of values.

In other words, *all* data types are restricted to a finite set of values, even if the set is pretty large. For example, `INT UNSIGNED` is restricted to the set of integers from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1. A pretty large set, but still finite.

ENUM just allows you a quick way to declare a much smaller set of values allowed in your column.

However, the syntax you show `ENUM(Y|N)` is not supported by MySQL. You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html for examples of the correct syntax.

I generally recommend to use ENUM when the set of values will not change, and will have no logical reason to change. The example of `ENUM('Y','N')` is fine, supposing there will never be a need for other choices for that column, like 'maybe' or 'partially'.

But I would not use ENUM for houseType or vehicleType, because it's likely to change over time, and it's inconvenient to add new values to an ENUM. You have to use `ALTER TABLE`. For cases of expanding enumerations, I'd use a lookup table. Then you can add a new allowed value simply by using `INSERT` to add a new row to the lookup table.